# Does WinDBG support multi-line commands?

Tags: windbg

For the sake of readability, it would be nice to be able to have multi-line "script" (whatever the syntax of WinDBG is called) code.

For example, I want to search through a chunk of memory looking for things that look somewhat like a wxArrayString...

```
r $t1 = 0xe53801c
r $t2 = 0x2e800
.for (r $t3 = 0; @$t3 < 0x400; r $t3 = @$t3 + 1) {
   .if (@@c++(
     ((int)(((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))->m_compareFunction) >= 0x10000) &&
     ((int)(((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))->m_pItems) >= 0x10000) &&
     (((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))->m_nCount <= 5000) &&
     (((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))->m_nCount > 0) &&
     (((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))->m_nSize <= 10000) &&
     (((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))->m_nSize > 0)
   )) {
     dx ((MyModule!wxArrayString*)(@$t1+@$t2+(@$t3*8)))
   }  
}
```

Smushing that into a single line isn't too hard, but it would be nice if I didn't have to do it every time I wanted to test a change in the code.

*Is there a way to do this (with line continuations or some other magic)?*

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftfeedback/WinDbg-Feedback/issues

Comment: @LexLi, is this a known limitation? That would at least be an answer to my question.

Comment: What is your command to run the script? Or do you copy/paste that into the WinDbg command window?

Comment: I'm copying/pasting, but could easily switch to running a script, I suppose.

Comment: I suppose the short answer to the actual question is: **No.** WinDBG does not support multiline commands in any sort of normal/reasonable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an editor that allows and supports files with different line endings (in one file!), it's feasible:

Insert Macintosh linebreaks (CR; `0x0D`) where you want to see line breaks and Unix line breaks (LF; `0x0A`) where you want WinDbg to end a statement.

[$<, $><, $$<, $$><, $$ >a<](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-----------------------a---run-script-file-#remarks) (MSDN; not some injection) has some details:

> The $$>< and $>< tokens execute the commands that are found in the script file literally, which means they open the script file, replace all carriage returns with semicolons, and execute the resulting text as a single command block.

Actually that statement is wrong. It replaces `0x0A` by semicolons and that is LF (line feed) and not carriage return (CR).

Example:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  2E 65 63 68 6F 20 22 57 6F 77 0D 2E 65 63 68 6F  .echo "Wow..echo
00000010  20 74 68 65 72 65 20 69 73 20 61 20 6C 69 6E 65   there is a line
00000020  62 72 65 61 6B 22 0A 72 20 24 74 30 0A 6B 20 4C  break".r $t0.k L
00000030  31
```

[image: Notepad++]

which looks like 4 lines but will be executed as 1 line:

```
2:004> $$>a< b:\newline.windbg
Wow .echo there is a linebreak
$t0=00000000
 # ChildEBP RetAddr      
00 0116f508 7726c088     ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b
```

The WinDbg command parser, scripting parser and whatever parsers are implemented ... erm ... in a quite simplistic way, I assume. They didn't think much about escape characters etc. Note that they do not care about the `"` of `.echo` and would even replace even replace LF in the middle of a string. There are plenty of examples which are like that.

Maybe you want to look into Python scripting with [pykd](/questions/tagged/pykd), implement a WinDbg extension or similar.

Comment: Ha! Using MS's own weaknesses to my advantage.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using pykd in this isntance because of it's requirement of an official Python install (it expects the registry data to run `py.exe`) and I only really have a portable install. I don't want to impose a bunch of prerequisites on systems where I'm likely to be iteratively developing this script code (customer machines, e.g.).

Comment: @mojo: got that. One of the reasons I also still use WinDbg scripts.

Answer (score 1):

are those numbers/address 10000  for m_compareFunction , m_pItems an example and not actual value ??

m_compareFunction is a Function Pointer

```
0:000> ?? labels[0].m_compareFunction
<function> * 0x00000000`00000000
```

m_pItems is a wxString *

```
0:000> ?? labels[0].m_pItems
class wxString * 0x000001c8`2553f598
   =00007ff7`cc3b8a60 npos             : 0xffffffff`ffffffff
   +0x000 m_impl           : std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >
   +0x028 m_convertedToChar : wxString::ConvertedBuffer<char>
```

also adding $t1+$t2 could be eliminated

anyway put your script in a txtfile like myscript.wds  and use
**$$>a< myscript.wds**
to execute it
you can write script as multiline

```
:\>cat d:\myscript.wds
r? $t0 = labels
?? @$t0
?? @$t0[0]
?? @$t0[1].m_pItems
?? @$t0[3].m_nCount
:\>
```

executed

```
0:000> $$>a< d:\myscript.wds
class wxArrayString [8] 0x00000035`350fe650
   +0x000 m_compareFunction : (null) 
   +0x008 m_nSize          : 0x20
   +0x010 m_nCount         : 0x13
   +0x018 m_pItems         : 0x000001c8`2553f598 wxString
   +0x020 m_autoSort       : 0
class wxArrayString
   +0x000 m_compareFunction : (null) 
   +0x008 m_nSize          : 0x20
   +0x010 m_nCount         : 0x13
   +0x018 m_pItems         : 0x000001c8`2553f598 wxString
   +0x020 m_autoSort       : 0
class wxString * 0x000001c8`26f40fa8
   =00007ff7`cc3b8a60 npos             : 0xffffffff`ffffffff
   +0x000 m_impl           : std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >
   +0x028 m_convertedToChar : wxString::ConvertedBuffer<char>
unsigned int64 0
```

also if you use r? you can eliminate all the casting

```
0:000> r @$t0 = 0x00000035`350fe654
0:000> r? $t19 = (widgets!wxArrayString *)@$t0
0:000> ?? @$t19
class wxArrayString * 0x00000035`350fe654
   +0x000 m_compareFunction : 0x00000020`00000000     int  +2000000000
   +0x008 m_nSize          : 0x00000013`00000000
   +0x010 m_nCount         : 0x2553f598`00000000
   +0x018 m_pItems         : 0x350ff800`000001c8 wxString
   +0x020 m_autoSort       : 35
```

Comment: `0x10000` is a sanity check for a pointer value. I.e. "is this a (valid) pointer?" There is no _real_ check for such a thing, but I'm trying to discern whether I should attempt to deference the pointer.

Comment: `r?` Aaargh! WinDBG has _so many_ commands! Thanks.