# windbg .shell passes the entire script to cmd, ending in "The command line is too long"

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to create a folder inside a windbg script file. If I just open windbg, I can do it using `.shell -ci "*" mkdir C:\mydir`. However, if I put the exact same command in my windbg script, I get error `The command line is too long`, and looking with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) I see that windbg passed the entire script to cmd.exe, not just my command.

DebuggerCommands.txt

```
.echo *** before mkdir ***
.shell -ci "*" mkdir C:\mydir
.echo *** after mkdir ***
$$ many other debugger commands saving stuff to c:\mydir...
```

Command:

```
windbg -c '$$>< DebuggerCommands.txt' notepad.exe
```

Result - windbg opens and shows:

```
0:000> $$>< DebuggerCommands.txt
*** before mkdir ***
The command line is too long.
.shell: Process exited

0:000>
```

And looking in Process Monitor, I see `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "mkdir C:\mydir;.echo *** after mkdir ***;$$ many other debugger commands...` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$$><` command condenses all statements into one single line [as specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-----------------------a---run-script-file-):

> Token $$><
>
> Condenses to a single command block: Yes

This on its own wouldn't matter much. But: some commands are not and can not be terminated by a semicolon.

One example is the [`.shell` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-shell--command-shell-):

> The entire line after the .shell command will be interpreted as a Windows command (even if it contains a semicolon).

So: you can't use `.shell` with `$$><`, `$><` and `$$>a<`. You might want to try if you can put it into a `.block{}`. Also: maybe `$<` or `$$<` (which don't condense the script) work.

Otherwise, try finding or implementing an extension with a !-command for this purpose. Perhaps [pykd](/questions/tagged/pykd) is an option. Just have one PyKD command in your script and let Python do the rest.

Another example where semicolons don't work ar [aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/as--as--set-alias-), since the alias would then simply contain the rest of the file. More obvious: [comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-----comment-specifier-). The rest of the file will be ignored.

Comment: Want more crazy stuff about running scripts? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69047883/480982 on how to abuse different line endings to your advantage.

Comment: Before going into writing long scripts, you want to know about the issues of WinDbg scripting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62314647/480982

Comment: `.block{}` works! Yes, I'm well aware of the extremely quirky windbg command syntax. The script is already written, I'm just moving stuff to a different directory, and trying to avoid adding a dependency to the installer, which has its own quirks.